# Change image path on current active item (only once)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a couple of blocks that each shows a div with text when clicked on it. The active block itself also changes class so the background color only is blue for the clicked element. In the blocks are images, which need to show a different image when active (same path as normal but only with the letter 'W' at the end, for example: img/images/img1.jpg becomes img/images/img1W.jpg).

My current jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.servicemark').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('data-toggle'));
        var type =  $(this).attr('data-toggle');
        $('.' + type).slideToggle("slide").siblings(".close1").hide();
        $(this).toggleClass("blauwblok").siblings().removeClass('blauwblok');
        });
});
</script>
```

My html markup (the data-toggle with the alias in it is the same as the classes in the text divs):

```
<section class="def-section home-services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <?php
        foreach($blocks as $block) {
          $images = json_decode($block->images);
          echo '
          <!-- === SERVICE ITEM === -->
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 servicemark" data-toggle="'.$block->alias.'" style="cursor:pointer;" id="blueblok">
            <div class="service-mark-border-top"></div>
            <div class="service-mark-border-right"></div>
            <div class="service-mark-border-bottom"></div>
            <div class="service-mark-border-left"></div>
                    <div class="service">
                        <div class="service-icon">
                            <img class="imgblok" src="cms/'.$images->image_intro.'" />
                        </div>
                        <h3>'.$block->title.'</h3>
                        <div class="service-text">
                            <p>'.$block->introtext.'</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          ';
        }
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row close1 zee-container-vervoer" style="display:none;">
            <div class="text">
                <p>Zee container vervoer Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc est neque, egestas et aliquam vitae, elementum eget neque. Donec fringilla purus nec viverra viverra. Nullam volutpat purus id risus sodales, id sodales sapien molestie. Phasellus bibendum massa et tellus aliquet rhoncus. Suspendisse accumsan, velit sed lacinia iaculis, sem neque condimentum magna, sed volutpat quam metus sed massa. Curabitur lobortis ligula sed consectetur consequat. Praesent suscipit, metus ac efficitur molestie, erat ante laoreet dolor, ut molestie felis est non est. Fusce dictum pulvinar nulla. Maecenas tincidunt vehicula enim, a porttitor magna mattis vel. In id erat in urna ornare porttitor. Aenean a hendrerit elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row close1 gevoelige-lading" style="display:none;">
            <div class="text">
                <p>Speciale lading Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc est neque, egestas et aliquam vitae, elementum eget neque. Donec fringilla purus nec viverra viverra. Nullam volutpat purus id risus sodales, id sodales sapien molestie. Phasellus bibendum massa et tellus aliquet rhoncus. Suspendisse accumsan, velit sed lacinia iaculis, sem neque condimentum magna, sed volutpat quam metus sed massa. Curabitur lobortis ligula sed consectetur consequat. Praesent suscipit, metus ac efficitur molestie, erat ante laoreet dolor, ut molestie felis est non est. Fusce dictum pulvinar nulla. Maecenas tincidunt vehicula enim, a porttitor magna mattis vel. In id erat in urna ornare porttitor. Aenean a hendrerit elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row close1 temperatuur-gevoelige-lading" style="display:none;">
            <div class="text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc est neque, egestas et aliquam vitae, elementum eget neque. Donec fringilla purus nec viverra viverra. Nullam volutpat purus id risus sodales, id sodales sapien molestie. Phasellus bibendum massa et tellus aliquet rhoncus. Suspendisse accumsan, velit sed lacinia iaculis, sem neque condimentum magna, sed volutpat quam metus sed massa. Curabitur lobortis ligula sed consectetur consequat. Praesent suscipit, metus ac efficitur molestie, erat ante laoreet dolor, ut molestie felis est non est. Fusce dictum pulvinar nulla. Maecenas tincidunt vehicula enim, a porttitor magna mattis vel. In id erat in urna ornare porttitor. Aenean a hendrerit elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row close1 explosieve-lading" style="display:none;">
            <div class="text">
                <p>Gevaarlijke stoffen Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc est neque, egestas et aliquam vitae, elementum eget neque. Donec fringilla purus nec viverra viverra. Nullam volutpat purus id risus sodales, id sodales sapien molestie. Phasellus bibendum massa et tellus aliquet rhoncus. Suspendisse accumsan, velit sed lacinia iaculis, sem neque condimentum magna, sed volutpat quam metus sed massa. Curabitur lobortis ligula sed consectetur consequat. Praesent suscipit, metus ac efficitur molestie, erat ante laoreet dolor, ut molestie felis est non est. Fusce dictum pulvinar nulla. Maecenas tincidunt vehicula enim, a porttitor magna mattis vel. In id erat in urna ornare porttitor. Aenean a hendrerit elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried adding the following code:

```
$(".imgblok").each(
        function(){
                p = $(this).attr('src');
                newp = p.replace('.png','W.png');
                $(this).attr('src',newp);
            }
        );
```

But this keeps adding the W whenever I click. I only need it to be changed once when there is no W present, else the path stops working. For testing sake I just added a class 'imgblok' to the img tag, but I need to have the path changed only on the active (clicked) element. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Where have you added `$(".imgblok").each(......` code?

Comment: I'm guessing in the click handler function.

Comment: @Satpal Yes inside the click handler, the code works, just not as I want it. It adds w every time i click and also doesn't see which one is clicked, but changes the path for all images.

Comment: Using magic strings is a bad habit. Make something which makes more semantic sense. Store the image links somewhere in the script and choose  the correct one, or make elements invisible based on a parent class. Image name is a value, not an indicator.

Comment: Also, to get the correct element you can use the `target` property of the event argument.

Comment: Do you need to replace `.png` when clicked?

Comment: @Satpal Yes, only add W just before the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this with the document `click event` and check if `W` is always in url with `substr` by example.

```js
$(document).on("click",".imgblok", function(){
  p = $(this).attr("src")
  if(p.substr(p.length-5,1) != "W"){
    $(this).attr("src",p.replace(".jpg","W.jpg"))
  }else{
    console.log("Always W")
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="imgblok" src="http://phaser.io/images/examples/2/thumb/bitmapdata/replace-color.jpg" />
```

Comment: Do I just add the whole code inside the click handler? My jquery is pretty bad, but this looks like a replacement of my click function instead of adding to it.

Comment: Yes you can paste inside your click handler. or add this code inside $(document).ready(){}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate through all images. Instead modify the `src` attribute in the click event handler.

```js
$('.imgblok').on('click', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    if (src.indexOf('W.png') === -1) {
        var newSrc = src.replace('.png', 'W.png');
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I have mistyped the image class name :( Edited the answer. And check whether you get correct values for src and newSrc fields.